# How do I make a div slide up and disappear in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

And just...poop, HTML gone. How do I do that? thanks.

I know about .hide() , but..I want permanently gone (for that one page), and slide up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `slideUp()` to slide it and then use `remove()` to remove it. Something like this:

```
$("#buttonid").click(function() {
    $("selector").slideUp("slow", function() { $(this).remove(); });
});
```

`remove()` will remove the element from the dom.

Comment: What if that is a button, and I want to remove a DIV called (result_item) that holds this button? The button is in another div itself though...

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand what you are asking here. I have updated my answer a little bit to show how you make this happen after a click on a element (your button). The remove() method will, however, remove all its child elements as well.

Comment: I have 3 nested DIVS ...which I want to be all removed. Inside the last child div, it contains the button. When the button gets pushed, I'd like the outer-most div to be removed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use .slideUp()

http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/

Answer (score 0):

You want the jQuery UI function called slide(), then call $(this).remove() in the callback, like so:

`$(function() {
    $('div').click(function() {
           $(this).slideUp('slow', function() { 
              $(this).remove();
           });
     });
 });`

Comment: What if that is a button, and I want to remove a DIV called (result_item) that holds this button? The button is in another div itself though...

Comment: So you want to remove the outer div wrapper only?